# svn xxdiff results in 0-byte files. help

Tags: svn, diff

'svn update' identifies conflicts and presents me with a diff. I have modified my SVN configuration so that the default 'diff' application is 'xxdiff'. I look over the conflict, see what I need to do, and exit 'xxdiff' with Ctrl-Q. The result seems to be that my local copy is replace with a 0-byte file. This is rather upsetting. Can someone tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

In case of **svn update** xxdiff activates **automatic merge mode**, but if there are conflicts a user interaction is required and according to the [doc](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/xxdiff-doc.html),

> In this mode, the user must save before exiting xxdiff (exiting will
>   prompt for save filename).

Also, you may want to try the [diff-proxy](http://xxdiff.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.2/diffproxy_8py_source.html) - a wrapper script that makes xdiff fully diff options compatible:

> xx-diff-proxy is a wrapper script for xxdiff that presents options
>   that are the same as the diff or diff3 commands. This can be used with
>   programs that expect to call diff/diff3 to present differences to
>   users, and can be configured with a different diff program.

As a workaround, you may provide a simple wrapper script (instead of directly using xxdiff in svn config) with **--merged-filename** option to change output file name (e.g. add **.merged** extension).